# What does it mean if you take the zero vector in the hyperplane separation theorem?

Tags: separation-axioms

If you have two disjoint sets V and W, which are compact and convex, then by the separation theorem there exists a vector u such that u*v< u*w.

However what does it mean if you take u=0?

Comment: The theorem states that there exists a $u$; you cannot choose it.

Comment: The separation theorem gives the existence of a non zero $u$.

Comment: If $u=0$ then $uv\not\lt uw$.